# App freezes when begin editing UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I've got two UITextFields `firstname` and `email`. I've got those as retained properties in my .h file and I synthesize them in my .m file. Editing the firstname field works fine. However as soon as I tap the email textfield to edit it, the app just freezes. It doesn't crash so there's nothing useful in the debugger.

This is what I have in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    firstname.delegate = self;
    email.delegate = self;
    email.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;    

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    email.leftView = paddingView;
    email.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    email.rightView = paddingView;
    email.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    firstname.leftView = paddingView;
    firstname.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    firstname.rightView = paddingView;
    firstname.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    [paddingView release];
  }
```

Anyone got a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: can u type text in email field

Comment: Nope, it freezes as soon as i select the textfield

Comment: does it also freezes if you dont set the paddingView to left and right? in other words: Is it the only stuff your class do with these textfields? I think the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok fixed it.

A single `UIView` (or `UIImageView`) cannot be displayed on screen twice at the same time. I fixed this by creating separate padding views for the `UITextField`s.

Comment: Mark this as answered by giving yourself the check.

Comment: to clarify, this is caused by displaying the same UIImageView object on screen more than once simultaneously (it appears the same UIView object must only be shown once) - i will suggest an edit

Answer (score -1):

What is the leftView here? and

> **why you are releasing the paddingView ???**

Try

```
[paddingView addSubView:firstname];
[paddingView addSubView:email];
```

Comment: You shouldn't release padding view if you assing it. I truly think that it's the reason for the crash.

Comment: Ehm the padding view provides a bit of padding within my textfield. My textfield shouldn't be withing the paddingview. Furthermore I release it because once I pass it to the leftview and rightview I don't need to own it anymore

Comment: Ok I think I don't fully understand when to release ownership of objects. Could you maybe explain tom me why I shouldn't release it?Thank you!

Comment: Explain me **what is paddingView is here**, you are just creating an object(may say just plain object which does not have any definition/objective).

Comment: It does have an objective: It provides paading within my uitextfield. Check out UITextField's class reference if you want to know more about  it's leftview property http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html